# Facebook Graph API Explorer URL parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API Explorer to do some debugging. In the admin interface of my application I want to provide a quick link that will open up the Graph Explorer with a Facebook object ID and an API token.

Something akin to:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?path=<object_id>&token=<token>&method=GET

I'm able to specify the path and the method parameters. Those input fields get properly populated on the page. However, I'm having trouble with token parameter. I tried "token" and "access_token", neither seems to populate the access_token input field. It just uses the default token.

Is there away to specify an API token as a parameter to this URL? Copy/Pasting it into the field every time is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, there is no way to add an access_token via the url for the explorer. One of the main points of the explorer is so you can look at endpoints without building a process to request a token.

If you're looking to see if a call works with your access_token, debug it and see if it has the permissions need. Or just simply build the call in your browser, its the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`access_token` is the param name you should use

If you replace the values and put it directly in a browser tab, it should work

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&
path=me/likes/
&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE
```

OR

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/likes?method=GET&format=json
&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE
```

But **make sure that you pass an valid access token** with the url